# When and where was the first use of the term Chimera?

Tags: architecture, d-wave, annealing, chimera, embedding

This is along the same lines as the earlier question: [When was the first use of the word Entanglement?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/when-was-the-first-use-of-the-word-entanglement)

I was surprised to discover that when searching for "chimera" in both of Vicky Choi's minor-embedding papers: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4884, 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3116,
no results came up!

This means that finding the first "chimera" paper is harder than I imagined and I don't know where to look anymore. When and where can I find the first use of the term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest non-internal reference I can find is in NIPS 2009 [from a Google/D-Wave effort](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//googleblogs/pdfs/nips_demoreport_120709_research.pdf)<sup>1</sup>.  You'll notice that the two Choi papers, in addition to not using the term "Chimera", do not describe a Chimera graph (and note that the name comes from D-Wave, not from graph theory).

For a good early reference on Chimera, I recommend [Bunyk et al., 2014](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6802426?arnumber=6802426)<sup>1</sup> , which describes graph theoretical and other practical considerations related to the architecture.

<sup>1 Note: I work at D-Wave</sup>