# Who first introduced the mathematical definition of entanglement?

Tags: entanglement, resource-request

I know the definition of entangled state and separable state from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_state), but I can't find the references that brought up the mathematical description of the entangled state and separable state. Is the definition brought up by someone?

Comment: Did you see this answer to a previous question? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2099/1837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name "entanglement" and the definition for pure states comes from Schrödinger 1935. The definition for mixed states comes from [Werner 1989](https://doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevA.40.4277)